# NSURLRequest results in 500 error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to make an api call using NSURL Request to upload an image and I continue to get 500 error. To show you what I'm trying to accomplish here is what the curl command would look like.

```
$ curl -i -F api_password=<YOUR_API_PASSWORD> -F file=@<LOCAL_FILE_PATH> https://upload.api.com/
```

Here is what I have so far and I continue to get 500 errors. Can you guys give me any direction on what I'm doing wrong (I'm no NSURLRequest master).

```
NSString *apiPass = @"apiKey";
NSString *filePath = imagePath;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.wistia.com"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// Create data string
NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"api_password=%@&file=@%@", apiPass, filePath];

NSData *postData = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

[request setHTTPBody:[dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSError * error = nil;

[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                      returningResponse:&response
                                  error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I want to upload "photo.jpg" to some server, I use code like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpg"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"photo.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:imageData];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", endItemBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

In this case data representation of image will be iploaded instead of link to image.
You can try someting like this.

Comment: Ah good to know I'll try that out. It's odd if I just put together a request without a body I get the expected 400 error but when I set the HTTPBody I always get a 500 error no matter what kind of data I put into it.

Comment: As I know, theres'no strong standart for image uploading. In some cases I even use Wireshark to construct right-formed requests. Now is time to communicate with support of service where you want to upload file, I think.

Comment: Turns out the way I was sending the data was causing the error. This  resolved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to compose your POST-request similar this:

```
NSString *boundary = @"---###-----##----##--#----###---BOUNDARY---###";
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *postString = nil;

postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary];
postString = [postString stringByAppendingString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_password\"\r\n\r\n"];
postString = [postString stringByAppendingString:apiPass];

postString = [postString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary]];
postString = [postString stringByAppendingString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n"];
postString = [postString stringByAppendingString:filePath];

postString = [postString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary]];

[postBody appendData:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.wistia.com"] 
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0f];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    

[request setValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];   
[request setValue:[@"multipart/form-data; boundary=" stringByAppendingString:boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postBody.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setHTTPBody:postBody];
```

Comment: Looks good. However, it could be improved through showing how to put image data into one multipart. It may also preferable to append `NSData` objects instead appending `NSString`s and then finally converting the string to a `NSData` object.

Comment: In initial code sample file is only path to file, as I can see. It looks strange, but all is possible. I think, in real situation there's need to prepare file as data to upload by using NSData dataWithhContentsOfURL or NSData dataWithContentsOfFile. And prepared NSData can be placed in body of POST-request as you describe abowe.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this. I'm still receiving a 500 error. I'm in contact with Wistia about the error so I'll post the resolution when I find it.

Comment: According http://wistia.com/doc/upload-api, you must to upload encoded file - not the link to file: "To upload a file from your computer, supply the required parameters and POST your media file to https://upload.wistia.com/ as multipart-form encoded data." See my next answer for example.

Answer (score 0):

Google for "error 500". It's "Internal Server Error". It's an error on the server. Nothing you can do except sending the server guys an email.

Comment: Error 500 may also be caused by a malformed message, or malformed Content-Type (e.g.: JSON).